# How to write greek, math, superscript/subscript in chaco?

Tags: python, enthought, chaco

Is there a way to write greek letters, math symbols and superscript/subscript in Chaco? I could find no way to do this. Tried using unicode strings, but they are just displayed as white squares.

Comment: "White squares" usually means your strings are sent correctly but the used font does not contain these characters.

Comment: @Jongware Do you know any font available to Chaco that will contain them?

Comment: I have no idea. Unless it has a font interface all of its own (highly unlikely), it should provide access to all fonts available in your Python installation, which may or may not come down to "all installed on your local system". If you happen to have a 'supercomplete' font such as Arial Unicode MS, you can test with that. Even a modern version of bog standard Times New Roman contains math and Greek (though not all superscripts).